# Convert AMPL to CPLEX

Tags: cplex, ampl

The following constraints are written in the AMPL environment and I want to convert it to a CPLEX?

```
subject to ex_one{b in B}: sum{t in T: t >= early[b]} y[b,t] <= 1;

#subject to most_one{tt in T, b not in BT[tt]}: sum{t in T} y[b,t] <= 1;

subject to grade1{t in T}: G_min*sum{b in B: early[b] <= t}(if g[b] > total[b] then 
total[b] else 0)*y[b,t] <= sum{b in B: early[b] <=t}(if g[b] > total[b]  then g[b] else 
0)*y[b,t];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert AMPL to CPLEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864348/how-do-i-convert-ampl-to-cplex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
range B=1..4;
range T=1..3;
{int} BT[t in T]=asSet(1..t);
int early[b in B]=b;

dvar boolean y[B][T];

subject to
{

forall(b in B)ex_one: sum(t in T: t >= early[b]) y[b,t] <= 1;

forall(tt in T, b in B:b not in BT[tt]) mostone: sum(t in T) y[b,t] <= 1;


 
}
```

works fine in OPL CPLEX