# How do I convert AMPL to CPLEX

Tags: cplex, ampl

The following set and parameters are written in the AMPL environment. How can they be converted to CPLEX?

```
set B;      #set of all blocks
set T;      #set of time periods
set BI{B};  #set of blocks that overlie a block
set BY{T};  #set of blocks that can be excavated in time period t
param C_min;        #minimum processing capacity of a mill
param g{B};     #average grade for block
param x_cord{B};    #x-coordinate of a block
param r{B} symbolic;
param early{B} default 1;
var alpha{B,T} binary;  # indicator for which sequencing constraint 6 won't be met
```

Also, the following Constraints are written in the AMPL environment. How can they be converted to CPLEX?(Especially the conditional part)

```
subject to processing{t in T}:  C_min <= sum{b in B: early[b] <= t}(if g[b] > total[b]  
then total[b] else 0)*y[b,t];

subject to sequencing{b in B, vb in B, t in T: early [b] <= t  and (x_cord[b]=x_cord[vb]) 
and 
(y_cord[b]=y_cord[vb]) and (z_cord[b] = z_cord[vb]-1)}: y[b,t] <= sum{u in 
early[vb]..t}y[vb,u];

subject to logic:sum{b in B, t in T} alpha[b,t] <= card(T)*card(B)-1;
```

in Cplex:

```
forall (t in T) {
processing:
C_min<=sum(b in B: early[b] <= t) 
[(g[b] > total[b])=> (total[b])(g[b] <= total[b])=>(0)]*y[b][t];
}

forall (b in B)
  forall (vb in B)
        forall (t in T:early [b] <= t  &&  
        (x_cord[b]==x_cord[vb]) && (y_cord[b]==y_cord[vb]) && (z_cord[b] == z_cord[vb]-1)){
        sequencing:                             
            y[b][t]<=sum(u in early[vb]..t) y[vb][u];
}   

logic:                          
        sum(b in B)sum(t in T) alpha[b][t]<= ??;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by CPLEX? Do you mean OPL? Or do you mean to write those things in a programming API? Did you look at the examples and tutorials for CPLEX? See for example here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/opl_KC_home.html.

Comment: I mean OPL. I have read CPLEX guide before and I know CPLEX. I just had trouble converting the above restrictions.

Comment: You have to show what `C_min`, `alpha` and `g` are. Are they decistion variables or parameters? Please also show the OPL model you have so far. For the `if`  in your condition, did you check the "implies" operator `=>`?

Comment: The requested parameters and variables as well as constraints were submitted in the CPLEX environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me help with the syntax

```
range B=1..4;
range T=1..3;
{int} BT[t in T]=asSet(1..t);
int early[b in B]=b;

int C_min=0;

dvar boolean y[B][T];
dvar boolean alpha[B][T];
dvar int g[B];
int total[B];
int x_cord[B];
int y_cord[B];
int z_cord[B];

subject to
{
  
  forall (t in T) {
processing:
C_min<=sum(b in B: early[b] <= t) 
((g[b] >= total[b])=> (total[b]*g[b] <= total[b]*y[b][t]));
}

forall (b in B)
  forall (vb in B)
        forall (t in T:early [b] <= t  &&  
        (x_cord[b]==x_cord[vb]) && (y_cord[b]==y_cord[vb]) && (z_cord[b] == z_cord[vb]-1)){
        sequencing:                             
            y[b][t]<=sum(u in early[vb]..t) y[vb][u];
}   

logic:                          
        sum(b in B)sum(t in T) alpha[b][t]<= card(asSet(T))*card(asSet(B))-1;;


 
}
```

works fine

Comment: g [b] is a parameter and is not variable and should not be given in the First constraint g[b]. The value of c_min cannot be zero. The First constraint does not appear to be properly equivalent.

Comment: I tried to help you with the syntax. If g is data and not decision variable then change dvar int g[B]; into int g[B];